# Docker: is it better to use two small containers or one big one

Tags: linux, docker

I am looking at Docker as an architecture for my next project.

I want to run a DNS server and a web server.

Is it better to put them both in the same container?  Or should I create two?

Do they need to stay loaded or do these containers sleep when there is no activity.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Docker philosophy is to isolate your functionality into discrete containers unless they are co-dependent.

For example, you might run dovecot and postfix in the same container, because they depend on one another.  They might also be split, if they share a common filesystem.

Apache and Bind are not co-dependent, and therefore may be split between containers.

In another virtualization technology (ex VMWare) , there would be a measurable overhead and the incentive to combine the functions may be greater.

The benefit of Docker is that the overhead is minimal, and the added benefit of being able to switch out and/or re-use the technologies outweighs the cost of overhead.

Ans:  Create two images, two containers.  If Apache is not the solution, then you can swap out the web services to NGINX without touching DNS.  Or add MYSQL in another container, and leave the DNS and APACHE unaffected.